# Xcode 6.3.1 iOS 8.3 UIWebView - Crash: *** -[MPAVRoutingController clearCachedRoutes]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mpavcontroller

Anyone seen that or know what's causing it?

Xcode 6.3.1
iOS 8.3

I have a UIWebView which displays an embedded Vimeo video. When tapped launches a full screen video.

This crash happens when I do a transition from the page with the the video, WITHOUT launching the fullscreen video.

Comment: It's caused by memory mismanagement.

Comment: There's nothing more to say. There are well known memory management issues in UIWebView, and you've encountered one of them. File a bug report with Apple. You could try switching to WKWebView - it is much better on memory management, though it has other problems / limitations of its own.